# jQuery .hover() only working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, hover

I need to add informational popups to several menu items, and Im using jQuery .hover to do so. However this only works in Firefox and does not work in Safari, Chrome or Opera.

```
var Main = function() {

    //other functions...

    function _setPopups() {
        $(".dt_event_title a").hover(
            function(){
                $(".info_popup",this).css({"display":"block"});
                //$(".info_popup",this).fadeTo("normal",1);
                //$(".info_popup",this).fadeIn("normal");
                //$(this).find(".info_popup").fadeIn("normal");

            },
            function(){
                $(".info_popup",this).css({"display":"none"});
                //$(".info_popup",this).fadeTo("normal",0);
                //$(".info_popup",this).fadeOut("normal");
                //$(this).find(".info_popup").fadeIn("normal");
            }
        );
    }
    return {
        //other methods...
        "setPopups" : function(){ _setPopups(); }
    };
}();
$(document).ready(function(){
    //other method calls...
    Main.setPopups();
});
```

My other methods are working in the context so my closure is fine. The commented-out jQuery lines represent other transformations I tried that produced the same results: works in Firefox, but not others. I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.

FYI the .info_popup div is given a css style display:none in an external style sheet to hide it.

Any help would be appreciated.

***Here is some of the html... note this represents the output, the html is largely generated by php

```
<tr class="dt_event_title">
   <td>
      <a class="dt_event_link" href="...php generated link...">
         <span class="info_icon"></span>
         <span class="event_title">Title of Event</span>
      </a>
      <div class="info_popup">   
         ...some php generated content
      </div>
      <div class="dt_event_date">
          09-15-2010 02:00 pm - 02:00 pm          
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Ok Here is the latest rearrangement of my code. The HTML now looks like this:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <div class="dt_event_title">
         <a class="dt_event_link" href="php generated link">
            <span class="info_icon"></span>
            <span class="event_title">php generated title</span>
         </a>
         <div class="dt_event_date">php generated date</div>
         <div class="info_popup">
            <div class='popup_title'>php generated title</div>
            <div class='popup_date'>php generated date</div>
            <div class='popup_time'>php generated time</div>
            <div class='popup_arrow'></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

And the javascript looks like this:

```
var Main = function() {

    function _setPopups() {
        $(".dt_event_title").hover(
            function(){
                $(".info_popup",$(this)).fadeIn("fast");
            },
            function(){
                $(".info_popup",$(this)).fadeOut("fast");
            }
        );
    }
    return {
        "setPopups" : function(){ _setPopups(); }
    };
}();
$(document).ready(function(){
    Main.setPopups();
});
```

And still the same problem.

Comment: What does the relevant HTML look like?  Specifically, what's in those `<a>` elements? Note in particular that block-level elements like `<div>` cannot be nested inside `<a>` tags, so perhaps this is IE's way of telling you that your markup is invalid.

Comment: I have no idea whats wrong, but just to let you know that instead of doing `.css({"display":"none"})` and `.css({"display":"block"})` you can use `.show()` and `.hide()` which do exactly the same thing. :) just a bit easier for you incase you didn't know. The jquery bit all looks fine... I don't recognise what you've done around the jquery, but the jquery bit should work. Maybe write it OUTSIDE of the fancy nested functions and see if it works - at least that way you know if its the jquery or the javascript.

Comment: I did indeed have block level elements inside my a tags, however even after restructuring so there are no div tags inside, the behavior is still the same... and to be clear, its not IE thats the problem. NO browser other than Firefox will work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Thomas. I did try show() and hide() as well (I tried several options). I also placed the code outside my closure to check that. Both gave the same results.

Comment: Can you include the associated HTML, specifically the menu and the pop up?

Comment: @Logic, please see my answer.  Your info_popup is not nested where it needs to be if you use a selector context.

Comment: See above changes. Ive moved my info_popup to be a direct child of the element being hovered.

Answer (score 2):

(Edited to use your html)

Since you are specifying a selector context (adding **,this** to your selector), the .info_popup element must be **inside** the this element.  Notice how the info_popup div is inside the a element.  *I'm not sure that's what you want, but it matches your code.*  **Since your info_popup is outside the a element, use `$(this).parent()` as your selector.**

I tossed this into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FUP6J/2/) for you.  I am using it in Chrome and it works.

Code below also:

HTML

```
<table>
<tr class="dt_event_title">
   <td>
      <a class="dt_event_link" href="...php generated link...">
         <span class="info_icon"></span>
         <span class="event_title">Title of Event</span>
      </a>
      <div class="info_popup">   
         ...some php generated content
      </div>
      <div class="dt_event_date">
          09-15-2010 02:00 pm - 02:00 pm          
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

CSS

```
.info_popup { display:none; }​
```

JS

```
var Main = function() {

    //other functions...
    function _setPopups() {
        $(".dt_event_title a").hover(
            function(){
                $(".info_popup",$(this).parent()).show(); //switched to .show() and $(this).parent()
                //$(".info_popup",this).fadeTo("normal",1);
                //$(".info_popup",this).fadeIn("normal");
                //$(this).find(".info_popup").fadeIn("normal");

            },
            function(){
                $(".info_popup",$(this).parent()).hide(); //switched to .hide() and $(this).parent()
                //$(".info_popup",this).fadeTo("normal",0);
                //$(".info_popup",this).fadeOut("normal");
                //$(this).find(".info_popup").fadeIn("normal");
            }
        );
    }
    return {
        //other methods...
        "setPopups" : function(){ _setPopups(); }
    };
}();
$(document).ready(function(){
    //other method calls...
    Main.setPopups();
});​
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried what you suggested and STILL the same results. I have tried many different ways of selecting, none seem to work in anything other than Firefox... Im going nuts

Comment: @Logic, Does the jsFiddle I posted that uses your html excerpt work for you?

Comment: So there's either a difference in your html or in your js.  Have you viewed the console to look for js errors?

Comment: I have run it through jslint and looked at it through firebug console and chrome's console...no js errors.

Comment: Are you completely sure the relevant pieces are identical to the jsFiddle?  Is this a public facing page you can link to?

Comment: please see the changes above.